# Javascript: Does the while loop (global) variable get discarded / reset when the loop finishes?

Tags: javascript, loops, variables, while-loop

In the code below I get an infinite loop because it seems that "i" keeps being reset to 0 when the inner loop finishes. This is causing the outer loop to never stop.

Is it true that variables get reset after the loop? I cannot find documentation on this.

```
  function chunk(arr, size) {  
    var twoDArr = [[],[]];
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    var index = 0;  

    while(i < arr.length){

      while(j < size && i < arr.length){
        twoDArr[index].push(arr[i]);
        j ++;
        i ++;
      }

    index ++;
    }

  return twoDArr;
  }

  chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f'], 2);

//-->  [ [ 'a', 'b' ], [ 'c', 'd' ],['f'] ]
```

Comment: And what's `index`?  I just ran this, setting `size = 10` and `index = 0` and it did not result in an infinite loop.

Comment: There is no reason the code that *you have posted* would cause an infinite loop. So whatever is happening, is happening in your `stuff happens here`. And the short answer to the question in the title is `no`.

Comment: If size is undefined, then will result into infinite loop. Check if size is defined or not.

Comment: Code edited to reflect the entire program. I was trying to simplify the code for easier reading purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is that you are skipping the inner loop on your second iteration through the outer loop, so `i` isn't updated and `i < arr.length` is always true. This is because you never reset `j` so `j < size` is false. To actually achieve what you want you need to reset `j` and build an array in the inner loop that you can `push` into your final array. Something like:

```js
function chunk(arr, size) {
  var twoDArr = [];
  var i = 0;

  while (i < arr.length) {
    var nestedArr = [];
    var j = 0;
    while (j < size && i < arr.length) {
      nestedArr.push(arr[i]);
      j++;
      i++;
    }
    twoDArr.push(nestedArr);
  }

  return twoDArr;
}

alert(JSON.stringify(chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f'], 2)));
```

Of course, you can make the whole thing more concise by using `reduce`:

```js
function chunk(arr, size) {
  return arr.reduce(function(p, c, idx) {
    if (idx % size) {
      p[p.length - 1].push(c);
    } else {
      p.push([c]);
    }
    return p;
  }, []);
}

alert(JSON.stringify(chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f'], 2)));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not resetting itself, but it only ever gets into the inner loop one time (where you increment `i`), therefor the outer loop is forever repeating (`i` becomes `2` in the inner loop and is never incremented after that).

You are probably looking to reset `j` after each inner loop, like:

```
while (i < arr.length) {
    while (j < size && i < arr.length) {
        // ...
    }
    j = 0;
    index++;
}
```

However, you should also be checking that `index` is within the bounds of `twoDArr`, as once you get to `index = 2` you're going to get an error at this line:

```
twoDArr[index].push();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(j < size && i < arr.length){
        twoDArr[index].push(arr[i]);
        j ++;
        i ++;
}
```

You are passing `2` as `size` to your function, so the inner loop will execute `index++` when `j < size && i < arr.length` returns `false`.

At your second time execution, `j` will be `2` so `j < 2` will be `false`.

The condition to finish the outer `while` loop is to `i > arr.length`, but `i++` is trapped inside a condition that will never be fulfilled.